# global max and min as limit to +-infinity equals 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

In an exercise I have to make I am asked to show that a function $f$ has a global maximum and minimum, given that:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.$$

However, in my mind, the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ satisfies those conditions and has an global maximum, but no minimum at all.

Am I misinterpreting the given information?

Comment: You are right, another counter-example is $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct, in that case by the [**EVT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) we can only claim that the function has (at least) *a maximum or a minimum*.

Comment: Okay thank you! I was beginning to doubt myself haha

Comment: @Renze Maybe the question contain just a typo for "and/or". You are welcome! Bye